# Why is my simple ajax post not calling the c# web method?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

I have a very simple AJAX Post that is not calling the C# Web Method.

When I add breakpoints to the JS, it seems to get to the AJAX post, but simply quit without making it to the Web Method. Any insight would be appreciated!

Jquery/AJAX:

```
$('#btnProcess').click(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < $('#fileList li').length; i++) {
        fileName = $('#fileList li')[i].innerText.substring(2, $('#fileList li')[i].length)

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Default.aspx/ReadFile',
            data: '{ fileName: ' + fileName + ' }',
        })
    }
})
```

C#/Web Method:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        string file = @"C:\Users\!user.a\" + fileName;
        Process.Start(file);

    }
```

Comment: @RyanWilson I've never formatted AJAX post the way you mention. Though I did attempt your solution, with no success.

Comment: @RyanWilson no luck. Thanks

Comment: Your readFile method is not being called?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro correct...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer through some trial and error. In this instance, I had to use JSON.stringify in order to pass the data to the Web Method. Below is the updated JS code:

```
$('#btnProcess').click(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < $('#fileList li').length; i++) {
        fileName = $('#fileList li')[i].innerText.substring(2, $('#fileList li')[i].length)
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'Default.aspx/ReadFile',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({'fileName': fileName})
        })
    }
})
```